# HTML CSS How to show popup login window

Tags: html, css, authentication, popup, panel

I am a beginner. I like to make a simple login popup after clicking on:

```
<li class="list">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon></span>
                    <span class="text">Logowanie</span>
                </a>
            </li>
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to invoke the popup function. Each time it takes me to a different page. I would like an example or help on how to combine it into one.

INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Panel Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li class="list active">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon></span>
                    <span class="text">Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="list">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="headset-outline"></ion-icon></span>
                    <span class="text">AudioBooki</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="list">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="book-outline"></ion-icon></span>
                    <span class="text">Ebooki</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="list">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="eye-outline"></ion-icon></span>
                    <span class="text">Poszukiwania</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="list">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon></span>
                    <span class="text">Logowanie</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <div class="indicator"></div>
        </ul>
    </div>
        

    <script>
        const list = document.querySelectorAll('.list');
        function activeLink(){
            list.forEach((item) =>
            item.classList.remove('active'));
            this.classList.add('active');
        }
        list.forEach((item) =>
        item.addEventListener('click',activeLink))
    </script>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

STYLE.CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

:root {
    --clr: #222327;
}

body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: var(--clr);
}

.navigation {
    width: 400px;
    height: 70px;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.navigation ul {
    display: flex;
    width: 350px;
}

.navigation ul li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.navigation ul li a {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.navigation ul li a .icon {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
    color: var(--clr);
}

.navigation ul li.active a .icon {
    transform: translateY(-32px);
}

.navigation ul li a .text {
    position: absolute;
    color: var(--clr);
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 00.75em;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(20px);
}

.navigation ul li.active a .text {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(10px);
}

.indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background: #29fd53;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 6px solid var(--clr);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.indicator::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -22px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: transparent;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow:  1px -10px 0 0 var(--clr);
}

.indicator::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -22px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: transparent;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow:  -1px -10px 0 0 var(--clr);
}

.navigation ul li:nth-child(1).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(calc(70px * 0));
}

.navigation ul li:nth-child(2).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(calc(70px * 1));
}

.navigation ul li:nth-child(3).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(calc(70px * 2));
}

.navigation ul li:nth-child(4).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(calc(70px * 3));
}

.navigation ul li:nth-child(5).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(calc(70px * 4));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of how to create a popup. I hope it helps you

```js
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */

.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/* The actual popup */

.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}


/* Popup arrow */

.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}


/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}


/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body style="text-align:center">

  <h2>Popup Example</h2>

  <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```